# Split character vector into separate rows

Tags: r, split

I have a data frame column, which is a list of words. I want to convert this list of words (each row), into long single list

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(words = c("a,b,c,d")),
            data.frame(words = c("a,b,c,e")),
            data.frame(words = c("d,a,b,a,b,c,d")))

> df
          words
1       a,b,c,d
2       a,b,c,e
3 d,a,b,a,b,c,d
```

I want a df such that each word from each row is a new row. 
    I am looking for a vector of elements

```
#Expected Output
a
b
c
d
a
b
c
e
d
a
b
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: `data.frame(new_row = unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$words), ",")))`

Comment: Ronak, can you please post this as an answer it is correct. Thank you

Comment: I am looking for a duplicate for this, if I can't find one I will post as an answer.